# Laravel - Logout redirects to home instead of logging out

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1. I have a custom logout function in `AuthController.php`, what I added on it is just calculating the total login hours of the user and just updating a specific table. My problem is when I click logout it just redirects me to `/home`, now, this doesn't happen all the time but it happens is fairly easy to reproduce. When I clicked logout it just redirects to `/home` then I clicked again, same thing. Sometimes I took me 4 attepmts to click the logout button before It logs out and send me to login page. What is happening here? Here's my code:

```
public function getLogout()
{

    if (Auth::check())
    {
        $userid = Auth::user()->id;

        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Taipei');

        $today = date('Y-m-d');
        $logHour = new LoginHour();
        $checkLogin = $logHour->checkLoginHoursOut(intval($userid), $today);

        if($checkLogin != null)
        {
            $loginhours = '';
            $timestamp = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
            $timestamp2 = strtotime($timestamp);

            $userLastLogin = $checkLogin[0]->timestamp;
            $userLastLogin2 = strtotime($userLastLogin);

            // Get difference in hours
            $diffHours = round(($timestamp2 - $userLastLogin2) / 3600, 2);


            LoginHour::where('date', '=', $today)->
                        where('user_id', '=', $userid)->
                        update(['loginhours' => $checkLogin[0]->loginhours + $diffHours, 'status' => 0, 'timestamp' => $timestamp]);
        }

        Auth::logout();

        return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/auth/login');

    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('/auth/login');
    }
}
```

Now you might notice I have a `Auth::check()` and I need that coz for some reason I don't know why I get a non-property object error in `$userid = Auth::user()->id;` But it's ok now, problem is I am redirected to `/home`

I have also declared `protected $redirectAfterLogout  = '/auth/login';` in top of my controller.

Comment: Can you try to remove code that doesn't have anything to do with your issue ? That would improve the question a lot :-)

Comment: @edi9999 That's my entire logout function :)  The reason I put them all is for others to find out what might be wrong in other parts. I believe I explained the issue well and code is not that long to be confused :)

Comment: May be you are not logged out successfully. Have you checked http://laravel.io/forum/11-09-2014-cant-logout-with-authlogout ?

Comment: I think its sends you back to the home page because of your else statement..so means you are still logged in. try to use maybe !Auth::guest() instead of the auth check..to check if you are guest or not.

Comment: @JLPuro Tried your suggestion, does not work either, I took me 5 attempts to successfully logged out :(

Comment: not sure if this will work but can you refactor the code a bit..like 
if (Auth::guest()) {return Redirect::to('/auth/login');}

 $userid = Auth::user()->id;

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Taipei'); etc...

Answer (score 2):

Tested in Laravel 5.3 / 5.4

Specify the URL it should redirect. In LoginController.

```
protected $redirectLogoutTo = '/login';
```

In LoginController override the logout method from AuthenticatesUsers Trait.

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->flush();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect($this->redirectLogoutTo); // only line that changes
}
```

Inside this method you can do also other stuff as you like.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is with handle RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware.
It checks the request and redirects to {domain}/home. Just remove it and handle using your controller.